# Reading a file and supplying the data in the file to a function

Tags: python

So basically I need to make some code which prompts the user for a filename and attempts to open whatever name is supplied. The program should then read each line from the file and supply it to the function I made which then turns the text in the file to a tuple.

So far I have this for the file:
https://i.gyazo.com/76db0e6bd91b0c457c40e4b1b692afd7.png

and this for the function:
https://i.gyazo.com/32e431a1ed638fb3072fe19e0c31d551.png

Comment: adding the screenshot of code is a bad idea, please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :

```
from os.path import isfile, exists

filename = input('Enter file name : ')

if(exists(filename) and isfile(filename)):     
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    # Call your function here with content as argument and process it, content has all lines in the file as a list
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of how the second function link that you shared fits here. But a generic solution for what you want to do is:

```
filepath = input("Message")

with open(filepath) as fp:  
   line = fp.readline()
   while line:
       line = fp.readline()
       custom_function(line) #Define and call your function
```

Hope it helps.